# set hour in DateTimePicker more than 23

Tags: datetimepicker

In my project , I need using Timepicker with format HH:MM , but I use it like duration , not a time , so is it possible to increase HH upto 99 , not stop in 23 !

I using datetime picker from this page : http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

After several time to edit js file , I found that I must change js code in "getUTCHours()" method from http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js file to get my goal !

But I cannot find the define of this method :(

Can anyone help me ? Thanks all in advances !

Valentino !

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible, the code has a condition that
whenever it detects the hour is equal or greater than 23
it will reset to 23.

In this code there is no limit.

In Bootstrap.timepicker.js

Search for  "23" or "24" in the code

You will find the following

```
`this.hour>=24?this.hour = 23`
```

I changed to

`this.hour>=24?this.hour = this.hour`  **without Limit.**

To make it Up to 99  changue it to.

```
`this.hour>99?this.hour = 99`     **UP to 99**
```

Be sure to use

```
`showMeridian = false`,
```

to make this work.

Im using "time" variable type in MYSQL and is working just fine.

Now it Works.

Comment: Where did you find those lines of code `this.hour>=24?this.hour = 23` and `showMeridian`? They are not in the JS linked at http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js ...