# Time Range on Bootstrap 3 or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to use a control like this one from [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#custom-formats), if the view is totally different but enables the functionality described bellow also would be not a problem.

But I would like to have the format **HH:MM:SS**, without ("PM"or "AM").
Without, with unlimited number of hourse (**HH**) and where you could accept a time range, for example: time just acceptable between "**11:12:02**" and "**11:30:20**" so other time wouldn't be even possible to select.

Answer (score 0):

Jon Thornton created a timepicker in Jquery for this type of time selection:

```
   $('#Example1').timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'h:i:s',
       'minTime': '11:12:02am',
       'maxTime': '11:30:20am'
    });
```

http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

Comment: Interesting :) The only problem it has is that it doesn't accept 'maxTime': '88:30:20' for example. The other requirements it fulfills. Please check it in here: http://jsfiddle.net/titombo/t2nn1689/

Comment: Dang, I tried to do it with days and that does not seem to work either. Sorry, I missed a vital requirement there.

Comment: Don't worry :) If there is not another good answer I will select yours, it was close ;)

Comment: It also doesn't work on bootstrap properly, should change a lot the CSS for the dropdown =/

Answer (score 0):

You can still use [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/):

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'HH:mm:ss',
    defaultDate: moment('11:12:02', 'HH:mm:ss'),
    minDate: moment('11:12:02', 'HH:mm:ss'),
    maxDate: moment('11:30:20', 'HH:mm:ss'),
    keepInvalid: true
});
```

Unfortunately, I think that there is no way to let the component show unlimited hours.

Comment: It seems it is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210054/set-hour-in-datetimepicker-more-than-23

I will make sure about that later